# Is there a semi-standard way to associate a URL with an IRC user?

Tags: url, irc, rfc

I'm in the process of doing some identity consolidation, so I'm providing URLs to me at various locations on the internet. I'm quite active on IRC, so this naturally lead me to wonder whether there was a way to provide a link to my IRC presence.

This lead to me finding http://www.w3.org/Addressing/draft-mirashi-url-irc-01.txt which appears to be a draft of an RFC for associating URLs with IRC, which suggests that I would be

irc://irc.freenode.net/DRMacIver,isnick

Which seems a little on the lame side. Further, this RFC draft has very thoroughly expired (February 28 1997). On the other hand it seems to be implemented in chatzilla at least:

http://www.mozilla.org/projects/rt-messaging/chatzilla/irc-urls.html

So does anyone know if there's a superseding RFC and/or any other de facto standard for this?

Answer (score 2):

I've been an IRC user for many years and I have never heard of any standards that allow you to do this (other than the RFC you mentioned).

I've always found IRC a very tricky place to keep track of users since it is such a simple thing to set up a bouncer and change your ident so easily.

Answer (score 0):

There's a newer draft https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-butcher-irc-url-04 that looks like it's basically the same except using isuser instead of isnick. It seems that isnick is more widely supported so it's probably better to use that.